# How can i set AND conditionals on Switchee?

Tags: switchee

Sorry but I'm unable to use switchee.. how can i set AND conditionals?

this is my original code:

```
<!--The Categories Page ////////////-->
{if segment_2=="" AND segment_3==""}
{embed="travels/travels"}

<!--The Category Entries Page //////-->
{if:elseif segment_2!="" AND segment_3==""}
{embed="travels/trip"}

<!--The Single Entry ///////////////-->
{if:elseif segment_3!=""}
{embed="travels/trip"}

{/if}
```

thanks!

Comment: In this case it would be more useful using ifelse than switchee. Developed from the same author: Marc Croxton.

Comment: Yeah! ifelse works well in this case, thank you Stéphane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, actually. You can concatenate both segments. I used to use some RegEx for this, but I just got the idea to take advantage of the parsing order.

Please, try this:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}/{segment_3}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="/"}
        {embed="travels/travels"}
    {/case}
    {case value="{segment_2}/"}
        {embed="travels/trip"}
    {/case}
    {case value="{segment_2}/{segment_3}"}
        {embed="travels/trip"}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

There's no performance gain by using switchee on this case because the [embeds are parsed after the advanced conditionals](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html).

Comment: Thank you Robson, I'll try your solution and the if else add-on by Marc Croxton too.. I really need to boost the performance